# How To Style Inactive Window?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mahapps.metro

I want that the Background changes to Gray if the Window is not the current active Window. I tried this:

```
<mm:MetroWindow.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type mm:MetroWindow}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</mm:MetroWindow.Style>
```

But it does not work, the Background is always Gray, even if the Window is in focus. Did I use the wrong Property or what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried setting background without a trigger? Just to check if it works.

Comment: yes, setting a background without a trigger works fine

Comment: Have you tried using `EventTrigger` and `EnterActions` and then use a `Storyboard` with Duration set to 0. And the event is `GotFocus`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `IsActive` property:

XAML:

```
    <Style x:Key="MetroWindowStyle2" TargetType="{x:Type Controls:MetroWindow}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsActive" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to add:

```
        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
        </Trigger>
```

(or whatever colour you want the background to be).

You might also have to add:

```
 <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="true"/>
```

to your style.

[Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.contentelement.isfocused(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: I tried this, but it does not work. Focusable is set to true and I tried to set a default-color by using your method as well as using a setter (in the style directly, not in a trigger). In both cases the trigger behaves as IsFocused is never true. There's also no binding error in the debug output.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the active background in the `Style` as well. There are several ways a background can by set, and the `Style` does not come high in the heirarchy. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

```
<mm:MetroWindow.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type mm:MetroWindow}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="someColour" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gray" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</mm:MetroWindow.Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I can see that you are using the theme MahApps.Metro. For that theme, you can just set the property '**NonActiveWindowTitleBrush**' as below to control the color of inactive window title. In my below example, I set the inactive window title as white.

```
<Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="CefSharp.MinimalExample.Wpf.MainWindow"                      
                      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:wpf="clr-namespace:CefSharp.Wpf;assembly=CefSharp.Wpf"
                    xmlns:cef="clr-namespace:CefSharp;assembly=CefSharp.Core"

                    xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
                    xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"   

                    NonActiveWindowTitleBrush="White"

>
```